# Vue on event selects first value only

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable, vue-events

I am using `vue-draggable` to drag my items. I am trying to print out the moved id using `:move="onDrop"` event and it prints out using `console.log(this.teamByTime2[0].id);` first value only. Lets take an example from my **DATA**, there is person called `KIM CHAN`, if i drag Kim then its suppose to print "5" not "4". Is there a way to solve that?

**View**

```
<div id="app">
    <draggable :list="dataList3" class="list-group" draggable=".item" group="a">
      <div
        class="list-group-item item"
        v-for="element in dataList3"
        :key="element.name"
      >{{ element.last_name }}</div>
    </draggable>

    <br>

    <div v-for="reservation in teamByTime2" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
      <draggable
        :list="reservation.Reservation_people"
        class="list-group"
        draggable=".item"
        group="a"
        :move="onDrop" <!-- I am using move event here -->
      >
        <div
          class="list-group-item item"
          v-for="element in reservation.Reservation_people"
          :key="element.id"
        >{{ element.last_name }}</div>
      </draggable>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Method**

```
onDrop(e) {
  console.log("moving teamByTime");
  console.log(this.teamByTime2[0].id); <!-- this only prints out first value -->

  <!-- is there a way to get the id actual moving/dragging item ? 
If I am moving Kim Chan from teamByTime, then the id is suppose to be 5 not 4 -->
}
```

**Data**

```
data: () => ({
    selectedid: "",

    dataList3: [
      { id: "1", first_name: "Jay", last_name: "Leo" },
      { id: "2", first_name: "David", last_name: "Reu" },
      { id: "3", first_name: "John", last_name: "Jac" }
    ],

    teamByTime2: [
      {
        id: "4",
        Reservation_people: [{ id: "18", first_name: "San", last_name: "lee" }]
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        Reservation_people: [{ id: "19", first_name: "Kim", last_name: "Chan" }]
      },
      {
        id: "6",
        Reservation_people: [{ id: "20", first_name: "Sun", last_name: "leo" }]
      }
    ]
  })
```

Here is my code below on `CODE SANDBOX`

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wildflower-sh4sk?file=/src/App.vue:874-1476

Answer (score 0):

`:move="onDrop"` is the short-form for `v-bind:move="onDrop"` which binds attribute `move` to a prop inside of the `draggable` component, or incase it doesnt exist as a prop inside of `draggable` it gets passed on to the root component that is the direct child of the `<template>` tag inside of `draggable`.

If you want to listen to the `move` event, you need to use the `v-on` directive, or its short form `@move="onDrop"`

Comment: I am already using @move="onDrop" event but it only prints out the first value, that's my error.

Comment: okay, could you maybe share the code of where you emit the move event?

Comment: so i assume you are using this [library](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) i cannot find a `move` event only a `moved` event. that one emits with 3 parameters, maybe you were looking for that?

Comment: If i use @start="drag=true" instead of :move="OnDrop' it will print out the value as "4" on console.log(this.teamByTime2[0].id); . If Kim Chan is dragged its suppose to print "5" as an id not "4".